# passing validation error from model to controller in zend framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

In Zend Framework,I am validating user supplied data in my model class something like

```
public function valiateRegisterForm($regisInfo)
{
   //validating with zend_filter_input which on failure returns array of arrays i.e
  //(error code to array of error messages) 
}
```

Right now i have create one more method getErrorMessage() to let controller to fetch error   message from model but then i have to create this method in my every model class which will   lead to redundancy,so should i create another object like ErrorManager?

To me it seems like as if am just not following things in proper way
please suggest some good method to handle error in zend framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible iam not understanding your questions but, i would return the Zend_Filter_Input object from your "validateRegisterFrom" method.The Object has an "getMessages" method wich returns the validation errors.

```
public function valiateRegisterForm($regisInfo)
{
      $filters = array();
      $validators = array();

      $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $regisInfo);

      // do validating

      return $input;
 }
```

and in your Controller

```
public function whateverAction()
{
     $result = $My_Model_Register->validateRegisterForm($data);

     if ($result->hasInvalid()) {
         $errors = $result->getMessages();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,In My model class i also have a method named register() so how should i make sure that this method will receive only validate data from controller.